# Check value in jquery

Tags: jquery, split

In my jquery i have code for showing some buttons:

```
if (values[1].length>0 && values[1]!=0) 
          {
            $("input[id="+id.slice(0,-1)+"].to-cart").show();
            $("input[id="+id.slice(0,-1)+"].to-cart").val("В корзину");
          };
```

But main trouble that i can have in values: >8, 4<, 3~ etc, but how to split only numbers in my variable? 
So my >8, 40<, 3~ i need to do for check, and view it as 8, 40, 3... but i have many symbols, not only ><

Comment: That seems like poorly filtered input. Your field should either contain numeric input or be constrained to a specific format.

Comment: @Asad this could'nt be done.... i simple must compare if value present, and is not null (but there are >< etc)

Comment: question isn't clear. Provide some sample data and a better explanation of what you need

Comment: @charlietfl added... but also it has if not clear, but good explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. You have strings like `">8"` or `"<4"` and you want to get the digit out of the string? If that is the problem you can use regular expressions:

```
pattern = /\d\;
digit = pattern.exec(">8");
```

This will return the `8`. If you know you'll deal with numbers with more than one digit your pattern should look like this:

```
pattern = /\d+\;
```

Comment: So you should use the latter pattern. It matches 1+ number of digits.

Comment: jquery could use .exec O_o ?

Comment: It's just plain JS. You can use any JS inside jQuery scripts if there's something you need to do and jQuery doesn't have it implemented. After all jQuery is still JavaScript ;)